# Fourier Transform of a Partial Derivative Squared - Using Fourier Transform to solve Nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fourier-transform

Definitions of Fourier Transform:
$$ \hat{v}(k,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}\ v(x,t) \ dx $$
$$ v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}\ \hat{v}(k,t) \ dk $$
Using these definitions, I was able to derive the fact that the transform takes partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and simply converts them to the transform of the function multiplied by a factor of $ik$. Conversely, the transform of the partial with respect to $t$ is simply the partial with respect to $t$ of the partial derivative. I was wondering however how the transform would act on the partial with respect to $x$ squared. I.e. what is the transform of:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 $$
Plugging into the definition, we have:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}\ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 \ dx $$
Following the lead of my first two calculations, I would like to use integration by parts to solve this however what would the antiderivative of the partial squared be? Is there possibly a simpler way of figuring this out? Thanks for any help!

Note, this is part of me trying to solve a nonlinear PDE. My thought was that maybe using either the $1$D (these definitions) or $2$D (in space and time) Fourier transform might help. However, I think the nonlinearities might preclude either of these methods from being fruitful. If this is true, are there any other analytic techniques that might aid me? The equation I want to solve is:
$$ u_t = u_{xxxx}-3u(u_x)^2-\frac{3}{2}u^2u_{xx}+\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}+F $$
where $F$ may or may not be a function of $u$ and its derivatives. I was hoping to be able to solve the equation with $F=0$ and then introducing it as an unknown function and seeing how it affects the solution.

EDIT: After thinking about this a little longer, I realized I may just be able to use the Convolution Theorem. Taking $ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, would the transform of this object simply be the convolution of it with itself:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\xi,t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x-\xi,t) \ d\xi $$
My broader questions still stump me a bit though. Even with this, I am unsure how this will help me in solving the PDE.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the Fourier transform will help you here. As you have pointed out you can use the convolution property to break up product, but what obtain at the end is arguably harder to solve than the original problem.

Comment: You might want to consider other methods. Perhaps see Chapter four of *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence Evans for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - that was my interpretation of the transformed equation as well. I appreciate the link as well I will see if there are any applicable ideas in the text from Evans